# Как получить координаты по кадастровому номеру земельного участка или здания?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

сейчас делаем сайт для Администрации района и стоит задача по кадастровому номеру земельного участка получать координаты (границы) участка и отображать эти границы на Яндекс.Карта и аналогично со зданиями. **Собственно вопрос в том, как получить координаты ?** Если брать допустим выписку Росреестра то там вроде как есть координаты, но я так понимаю что они не подойдут для Яндекс.Карты, т.к. говорят что координаты в местной системе координат и их необходимо переводить, а для этого должны быть ключи перевода, а они являются секретными. Я уже думаю что может быть нужно что бы администрация сделала запрос в Росреестра и может быть они дадут какие нибудь доступы. **Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить координаты по кадастровому номеру и отобразить эти координаты на Яндекс.Карте.** Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: У росреестра какой-то свой особый глобус?

Comment: @Alexey Ten вряд ли, но как мне сказали что координаты там в местной системе координат, в выписках

Comment: Простой ответ - никак; вам нужно отображать границы участков и их надо получать непосредственно от владельца информации. Если владелец информации зашифровал координаты, то либо они должны дать ключ, либо вы уже отображаете не их информацию (мало ли кто в интернете какие границы кадастровых участков нарисовал - это же как раз они "засекречены" в шифрованных координатах)